# Why am I getting an assertion error when create Device Quantile Matrix?

Tags: python, dask, rapids, cudf

I am using the following code to load a csv file into a dask cudf, and then creating a devicequantilematrix for xgboost which yields the error:

```
cluster = LocalCUDACluster(rmm_pool_size=parse_bytes("9GB"), n_workers=5, threads_per_worker=1)
client = Client(cluster)

ddb = dask_cudf.read_csv('/home/ubuntu/dataset.csv')
xTrain = ddb.iloc[:,20:]
yTrain = ddb.iloc[:,1:2]

dTrain = xgb.dask.DaskDeviceQuantileDMatrix(client=client, data=xTrain, label=yTrain)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-2cca13ac807f> in <module>
----> 1 dTrain = xgb.dask.DaskDeviceQuantileDMatrix(client=client, data=xTrain, label=yTrain)

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/dask.py in __init__(self, client, data, label, missing, weight, base_margin, label_lower_bound, label_upper_bound, feature_names, feature_types, max_bin)
    508                          label_upper_bound=label_upper_bound,
    509                          feature_names=feature_names,
--> 510                          feature_types=feature_types)
    511         self.max_bin = max_bin
    512         self.is_quantile = True

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/dask.py in __init__(self, client, data, label, missing, weight, base_margin, label_lower_bound, label_upper_bound, feature_names, feature_types)
    229                                  base_margin=base_margin,
    230                                  label_lower_bound=label_lower_bound,
--> 231                                  label_upper_bound=label_upper_bound)
    232 
    233     def __await__(self):

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in sync(self, func, asynchronous, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    835         else:
    836             return sync(
--> 837                 self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
    838             )
    839 

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in sync(loop, func, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    338     if error[0]:
    339         typ, exc, tb = error[0]
--> 340         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    341     else:
    342         return result[0]

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in f()
    322             if callback_timeout is not None:
    323                 future = asyncio.wait_for(future, callback_timeout)
--> 324             result[0] = yield future
    325         except Exception as exc:
    326             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
    760 
    761                     try:
--> 762                         value = future.result()
    763                     except Exception:
    764                         exc_info = sys.exc_info()

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/dask.py in map_local_data(self, client, data, label, weights, base_margin, label_lower_bound, label_upper_bound)
    311 
    312         for part in parts:
--> 313             assert part.status == 'finished'
    314 
    315         # Preserving the partition order for prediction.

AssertionError:
```

I have no idea what this error is caused by since it doesn't say anything other than "assertion error". I have a large dataset that is too big to read into a single GPU so I am using dask_cudf to split it up when I read it from disk, and then feeding it directly into the data structure required for XGBoost. I'm not sure whether its a dask_cudf problem or an XGBoost problem.

New error when I use the "wait" while persisting:

```
distributed.core - ERROR - 2154341415 exceeds max_bin_len(2147483647)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 563, in handle_stream
    handler(**merge(extra, msg))
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 2382, in update_graph_hlg
    dsk, dependencies, annotations = highlevelgraph_unpack(hlg)
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/highlevelgraph.py", line 161, in highlevelgraph_unpack
    hlg = loads_msgpack(*dumped_hlg)
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 223, in loads_msgpack
    payload, object_hook=msgpack_decode_default, use_list=False, **msgpack_opts
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 195, in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb
ValueError: 2154341415 exceeds max_bin_len(2147483647)
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback <bound method Client._heartbeat of <Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:43507' processes=4 threads=4, memory=49.45 GB>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 905, in _run
    return self.callback()
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1177, in _heartbeat
    self.scheduler_comm.send({"op": "heartbeat-client"})
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/batched.py", line 136, in send
    raise CommClosedError
distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError
distributed.core - ERROR - Exception while handling op register-client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 491, in handle_comm
    result = await result
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 3247, in add_client
    await self.handle_stream(comm=comm, extra={"client": client})
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 563, in handle_stream
    handler(**merge(extra, msg))
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 2382, in update_graph_hlg
    dsk, dependencies, annotations = highlevelgraph_unpack(hlg)
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/highlevelgraph.py", line 161, in highlevelgraph_unpack
    hlg = loads_msgpack(*dumped_hlg)
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 223, in loads_msgpack
    payload, object_hook=msgpack_decode_default, use_list=False, **msgpack_opts
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 195, in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb
ValueError: 2154341415 exceeds max_bin_len(2147483647)
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<function TCPServer._handle_connection.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f7058e87f80>, <Task finished coro=<BaseTCPListener._handle_stream() done, defined at /usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py:459> exception=ValueError('2154341415 exceeds max_bin_len(2147483647)')>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 741, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 331, in <lambda>
    gen.convert_yielded(future), lambda f: f.result()
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 476, in _handle_stream
    await self.comm_handler(comm)
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 491, in handle_comm
    result = await result
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 3247, in add_client
    await self.handle_stream(comm=comm, extra={"client": client})
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 563, in handle_stream
    handler(**merge(extra, msg))
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py", line 2382, in update_graph_hlg
    dsk, dependencies, annotations = highlevelgraph_unpack(hlg)
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/highlevelgraph.py", line 161, in highlevelgraph_unpack
    hlg = loads_msgpack(*dumped_hlg)
  File "/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 223, in loads_msgpack
    payload, object_hook=msgpack_decode_default, use_list=False, **msgpack_opts
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 195, in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb
ValueError: 2154341415 exceeds max_bin_len(2147483647)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e2b8073da6e7> in <module>
      1 from dask.distributed import wait
----> 2 wait([xTrainDC,yTrainDC])

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in wait(fs, timeout, return_when)
   4257     """
   4258     client = default_client()
-> 4259     result = client.sync(_wait, fs, timeout=timeout, return_when=return_when)
   4260     return result
   4261 

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in sync(self, func, asynchronous, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    835         else:
    836             return sync(
--> 837                 self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
    838             )
    839 

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in sync(loop, func, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    338     if error[0]:
    339         typ, exc, tb = error[0]
--> 340         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    341     else:
    342         return result[0]

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in f()
    322             if callback_timeout is not None:
    323                 future = asyncio.wait_for(future, callback_timeout)
--> 324             result[0] = yield future
    325         except Exception as exc:
    326             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
    760 
    761                     try:
--> 762                         value = future.result()
    763                     except Exception:
    764                         exc_info = sys.exc_info()

CancelledError:
```

Comment: Can you post versions of cudf, xgboost, dask, distributed, and dask-cuda ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's something in the `dask_cudf.read_csv('/home/ubuntu/dataset.csv')` failing which causes the underlying future status to not be `finished`. Does the CSV fit in GPU memory across the GPUs you're using? Could you try the following code and report back the error message?

This will tell dask to compute the result of the `read_csv` and `iloc` functions and wait for the distributed result to be finished before moving onto creating the `DMatrix`.

```py
from dask.distributed import wait

cluster = LocalCUDACluster(rmm_pool_size=parse_bytes("9GB"), n_workers=5, threads_per_worker=1)
client = Client(cluster)

ddb = dask_cudf.read_csv('/home/ubuntu/dataset.csv')
xTrain = ddb.iloc[:,20:].persist()
yTrain = ddb.iloc[:,1:2].persist()
wait([xTrain, yTrain])

dTrain = xgb.dask.DaskDeviceQuantileDMatrix(client=client, data=xTrain, label=yTrain)
```

Comment: Not 100% sure about CSV fitting across GPUs... its 25GB on disk and I have 6x 1080ti's... so it should fit in theory. I've added the new error message when I add in the "wait" line above.